# Not sure if i am messing up the hover or the IF Then

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok as always in my mind this should work but i am new to javascript and trying a lot of things at once. This is a nav bar that shows and hides divs while change color of the nav when clicked or hover over. well it does not do that last part. The active ID is the one that is currently displayed. Sorry i now it is nothing simple.

```
$(function () {
    var active;

    $('.selection').hide();
    $('#homeDiv').show();

    $('.navlink').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#806ac7");
    },

    function () {
        if ($(this == active)) {
            $(this).css("color", "#961014");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "#000000");
        }
    });
    $('.navLink').click(function (e) {
        active == $(this);
        $('.navLink').css("color", "#000000");
        $(this).css("color", "#961014");
        $('.selection').hide();
        $('#' + this.id + 'Div').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `if($(this == active)) {` Well... you're passing a boolean to `jQuery()`, which will return an object, which is always "truthy".

Comment: and inside your click event `active == $(this)` equates to `false`, then does nothing with `false`. `active` is still `undefined`

Comment: Also, there's no reason to do `$('#' + this.id + 'Div').show();`, when you can just do `$(this).find('div').show();` *(also notice the lowercase `d` in `div`)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what I noted in my comment under the question, you need to store the element, not a jQuery object, and that compare the elements.

If you try to compare the result of different calls to `$(this)`, it will always be `false`, because they're unique objects.

```
$(function () {
    var active;

    $('.selection').hide();
    $('#homeDiv').show();

    $('.navlink').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#806ac7");
    },

    function () {
           // RIGHT HERE, compare the element
        if (this === active) {
            $(this).css("color", "#961014");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "#000000");
        }
    });
    $('.navLink').click(function (e) {

        // RIGHT HERE, store the element
        active = this;

        $('.navLink').css("color", "#000000");
        $(this).css("color", "#961014");
        $('.selection').hide();

         // Lowercase "D" in "div", and improved DOM selection
        $(this).find('div').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: nothing explicitly wrong with storing the jquery object. Probably not as performant though.

Comment: active == this; shouldn't it be active = this ?

Comment: `active == this;` should be `active = this;`

Comment: @Kostia: Except that it was being used for a comparison to `this` in another function. If we store the jQuery object, it will never compare equally to a different jQuery object. We would need to extract the element before the comparison is done.

Comment: @Huangism: Yes, thanks. Didn't notice that error in the question.

Comment: navlink <> navLink that was the main problem. it is always the small things.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you misplaced your closing bracket in this line: `if ($(this == active))`. It should actually be `if (this == active)`

Also, you are writing a boolean instead of setting a variable: `active == $(this)` which should be `active = this;`

Comment: Your `==` comparison will always be `false`, because objects are compared based on identity, so `$(this) == active` will always be comparing two different objects.

Comment: @CrazyTrain touche. Somehow thought jquery would cache the selector.

Comment: It does store the element at index `0`, so you could do `$(this)[0] == active`, but then you'd be creating a jQuery object, and immediately throwing it away. But the `==` just sees them as objects, and checks to see if they're the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do what you want, is to add a class when the user clicks on your nav items. In your hover handler, check for the class and change the colour accordingly. Or you can simply use important in the css to set the active colour, so you don't need to check for active in your hover

```
$('.navLink').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('open').css("color", "#961014");
    $('.navLink').css("color", "#000000");
    $('.selection').hide();
    $('#' + this.id + 'Div').show();
});

$('.navlink').hover(

function () {
    $(this).css("color", "#806ac7");
},

function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('open') {
        $this.css("color", "#961014");
    } else {
        $this.css("color", "#000000");
    }
});
```

The solution above is using jquery to change the css colour but you can easily do it in css. Assuming the rest of your code works

Comment: I know a lot more CSS then i do javascript, so i did try this first. the problem is with 'active' selector only works with links not li, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: @user2428881 my solution does not involve the :active selector at all, instead it adds a class named active, of course this you can change to whatever you want. You define the important css on the active class not :active. I will change it to something that's less confusing. Changed active to open,this is just a css class

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var active;

    $('.selection').hide();
    $('#homeDiv').show();

    $('.navLink').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#806ac7");
    },

    function () {
        if (active == this || active == undefined) {
            $(this).css("color", "#961014");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "#000000");
        }
    });
    $('.navLink').click(function (e) {
        active = this;
        $('.navLink').css("color", "#000000");
        $(this).css("color", "#961014");
        $('.selection').hide();
        $('#' + this.id + 'Div').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3heA/